# How do I generate manpages using escape codes for bold, etc.?

Tags: man, less, groff, roff

While inspecting [the source code of `less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html), I noticed that the included manpage (`less.man`) used terminal escape codes for showing bold text:

```
^[[1mNAME^[[0m
       less - opposite of more

^[[1mSYNOPSIS^[[0m
       ^[[1mless -?^[[0m
       ^[[1mless --help^[[0m
       ^[[1mless -V^[[0m
       ^[[1mless --version^[[0m
       ^[[1mless [-[+]aABcCdeEfFgGiIJKLmMnNqQrRsSuUVwWX~]^[[0m
```

The command used to generate is apparently `nroff -man`:

```
$ head Makefile.aut 
# Makefile for authoring less.

EMAIL = bug-less@gnu.org
HOMEPAGE = http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less
SHELL = /bin/sh
RCS = rcs
NROFF = nroff -man
```

Yet, if I run `nroff -man less.nro`, I get the (usual) manpage output using backspaces:

```
N^HNA^HAM^HME^HE
       less - opposite of more

S^HSY^HYN^HNO^HOP^HPS^HSI^HIS^HS
       l^Hle^Hes^Hss^Hs -^H-?^H?
       l^Hle^Hes^Hss^Hs -^H--^H-h^Hhe^Hel^Hlp^Hp
       l^Hle^Hes^Hss^Hs -^H-V^HV
       l^Hle^Hes^Hss^Hs -^H--^H-v^Hve^Her^Hrs^Hsi^Hio^Hon^Hn
```

How do I generate the first form?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "first form" is a... feature of [`groff`](http://www.gnu.org/software/groff/).  If your "nroff" is not a wrapper for `groff`, you will see only the second form.

The feature is referred to in the manual page for [`grotty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grotty.1.html) (groff driver for typewriter-like devices):

> By  default,  **grotty**  emits  SGR  escape sequences (from ISO 6429, also called ANSI color escapes) to
>   change text attributes (bold, italic, colors).  This makes it possible to have eight different  back-ground background
>   ground  and  foreground colors; additionally, bold and italic attributes can be used *at the same time*
>   (by using the BI font).

In practice, it does not work well, e.g., see how the same comment (post-processing those sequences) is [misrendered here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grotty):

> By default, **grotty** emits SGR escape sequences (from ISO 6429, also called ANSI color escapes) to change text attributes (bold, italic, colors). This makes it possible to have eight different *M[green]backgroundM[]* and *m[red]foregroundm[]* colors; additionally, bold and italic attributes can be used *BI]at the same time]* (by using the BI font).

and for that reason, some developers choose not to use it (e.g., [this discussion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2004-03/msg00239.html) from Emacs mailing list).

However, as the manual page says **"By default"**.  So, if you have groff, then it should be producing those escape sequences.

Packagers may apply patches to modify programs.  A comment by @muru mentions the version in Debian (see [bug reports](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=groff-base;dist=unstable) and [package page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/groff-base)).  The package changelog says this:

```
 -- Colin Watson <cjwatson@debian.org>  Sat, 27 Jul 2002 18:41:46 +0100
groff (1.18-1) unstable; urgency=low 

  * Disable the new ANSI colour/bold/underline escapes in nroff mode,
    because most pagers either fail to cope with it or need special options
    to do so. It can be re-enabled by editing /etc/groff/man.local and
    /etc/groff/mdoc.local, or by setting the environment variable GROFF_SGR
    to something non-empty.
```

However, the groff source does not mention **`GROFF_SGR`**; it has only references to **`GROFF_NO_SGR`**:

```
./NEWS:1108:  for the GROFF_NO_SGR environment variable also.
./NEWS:1450:o If the environment variable GROFF_NO_SGR is set, SGR output is disa...
./PROBLEMS:33:  1. Set the GROFF_NO_SGR environment variable.
./doc/webpage.ms:1920:.  URL #GROFF_NO_SGR GROFF_NO_SGR
./doc/webpagewebpage.ms:1922:. nop GROFF_NO_SGR
./doc/webpagewebpage.ms:2437:.TAG GROFF_NO_SGR        
./doc/webpagewebpage.ms:2439:If the environment variable GROFF_NO_SGR is set, SGR output is 
./src/devices/grotty/grotty.man:126:.B GROFF_NO_SGR
./src/devices/grotty/grotty.man:394:.B GROFF_NO_SGR
./src/devices/grotty/tty.cpp:864:  if (getenv("GROFF_NO_SGR"))
```

and the changelog (ChangeLog.118) gives no clue:

```
2002-02-12  Werner LEMBERG  <wl@gnu.org>

        * src/libs/libgroff/Makefile.sub (snprintf.o): Don't use
        $(COMPILE.c) to not include groff's assert.h.        
        * src/drivers/grotty/tty.cc (main): Add GROFF_NO_SGR environment
        variable.                           
        * NEWS, src/drivers/grotty/grotty.man: Document it.
```

Setting `GROFF_NO_SGR` will not give SGR sequences (the manpage is correct).  The Debian changelog comment refers to this chunk from `/etc/groff/man.local`, where Debian added a check for the `GROFF_SGR` variable:

```
.  \" Debian: Disable the use of SGR (ANSI colour) escape sequences by
.  \" grotty. 
.  if '\V[GROFF_SGR]'' \
.    output x X tty: sgr 0
```

and setting the environment variable does make it generate SGR sequences for bold, etc.

Comment: I do have `groff` and my `nroff` is a wrapper for `groff` (it apparently runs `PATH="$GROFF_RUNTIME$PATH" groff -mtty-char $T $opts ${1+"$@"}`

Comment: Hmm. So it's a idea bad enough that the package maintainers disabled it. Ah, well.