# Purpose of “ASCII text, with overstriking” file format

Tags: man, documentation, text-formatting

After downloading the source code for Bash, I was browsing through the `doc` directory and came across the following files:

- [`bash.1`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/bash.1) is a regular [troff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff) file used to build the *man page*.
- [`bash.0`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/bash.0) is like a plain text version of the man page – only that it has the [`^H` backspace control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH) liberally distributed throughout it.

These control characters are not displayed in the representation provided by the Git web interface but the [actual file can be downloaded](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/doc/bash.0) and examined in text editor such as Vim.

Running the `file` command on `bash.0` prints the following output:

```
bash.0: ASCII text, with overstriking
```

I’ve never come across this file format before and I was wondering what its purpose is and how it’s used. Searching the Web for the phrase *“ASCII text, with overstriking”* hasn’t been very enlightening.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A web search for [*"backspace" and "overstrike"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=backspace%20overstrike&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) would get better results.

The file is a manual page — formatted using [`nroff`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/nroff). Usually files such as `bash.0` are simply generated and discarded.  A while back, they were saved, to reduce work for the `man` program.  Rather than `/usr/share/man/man1`, your manual pages would be read from `/usr/share/man/cat1`.  Read the description of [`catman`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/catman.8.html) for instance.

`nroff` is the Unix command for formatting manual pages and other files.  Back when it was first written, there were several other utilities, each with its own markup language.  I've used at least a dozen different ones.  But they all solved the problem of printing emphasized text in the same way: using carriage control.  *Backspaces* are just noticeable because they are not used in other plain-text files.  *Tabs*, *carriage returns*, *line-feeds* and *form-feeds* all have a role in plain text files (though form-feeds are far less important than they were originally).

`nroff` uses underlining to indicate *italics* and overstriking to represent **bold**.  The technique is dated: it is useful for hard-copy devices where more than one character can be printed in the same position.  Very few video terminals do that.  In [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html), that would be

```
   over_strike               os     os   terminal can over-
                                         strike
```

or more [completely](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Basic-Capabilities):

> If the terminal *overstrikes* (rather than clearing a
>   position when a character is struck over) then  it  should
>   have  the  **`os`**  capability.

In the usual case, the last character written on a given row/column of a video terminal would be *all* that is shown.  `nroff` organized the output so that an underlined character was written as an underline, a backspace and the actual character.  Doing that ensured that terminals without the overstrike feature would print something useful.

Among the very few video terminals listed which have the overstrike capability, I see the [DEC gt40](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-gt40), which I used for about three years (1976-1979).  There was no Unix on that system (it ran RT-11), but I wrote a [text formatter](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#txt), using the same type of overstruck text.  Ultimately, I needed hardcopy, and wrote a [utility](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#unover) to make that happen — something like [`col`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html), perhaps — but solving a related problem.  The terminal printed very slowly when it had a lot of underlined text, until my program reorganized the text to reduce the amount of switching between forward/backward motion.

With video terminals, there is no need for that.  But they do not do overstriking.  Instead, we have programs that recognize the underlining and *show* underlines, or have [`groff`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/groff.1.html), which might show colored text instead of underlining (and bold).

Further reading:

- [How do I generate manpages using escape codes for bold, etc.?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243953/how-do-i-generate-manpages-using-escape-codes-for-bold-etc/243973#243973)
- [catman - create or update the pre-formatted manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/catman.8.html)
- [repaginator](http://invisible-island.net/personal/oldprogs.html#repaginator) (for your amusement)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer with interesting historical background. It's late at night for me so I'll read it properly tomorrow. FWIW, I actually upvoted your answer on generating man pages earlier today when I was researching the \*roff family of text formatters.

Answer (score 48):

Overstriking is a method used in `nroff` (see the [Troff User’s Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20150205025959/http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/troff.pdf)) to offer more typographical possibilities than plain ASCII would allow:

- bold text (by overstriking the same character)
- underlined text (by overstriking `_`)
- accents and diacritics (*e.g.* `é` produced by overstriking `e` with `’`)

and various other symbols, as permitted by the target output device.

In `bash`, these `.0` files are produced directly by `nroff`, with `Makefile` rules such as

```
.1.0:
        $(RM) $@
        -${NROFF} -man $< > $@
```

You can view such files using `less`; it will process the overstriking sequences and replace them as appropriate:

```
less bash.0
```

Originally `nroff`'s output targeted typewriter-style output devices, which would back up every time they received a backspace character; overstriking would produce the desired visual output. As pointed out by [chirlu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38305/chirlu), striking the same character twice would usually result in a bolder appearance thanks to the inevitable misalignment of the successive strikes; the increase in the amount of ink deposited would also help.

(`troff` targeted typesetting machines.)

Comment: *"`nroff`'s output targeted typewriter-style output devices" ... " `troff` targeted typesetting machines"* So why are these both installed on my personal laptop? :P

Answer (score 7):

And even earlier, it was a method of printing on golf-ball printers that worked like old typewriters and had a very limited set of characters that they could print.  So nroff uses the byte stream of an old teletype printer to represent how to should look 'on screen'.

Comment: `nroff` actually was designed initially to print on typewriters, as opposed to `troff` which targeted typesetters. Using screens for output came later...

Comment: I'm old enough to have used a mechanical typewriter where you typed `!` by typing `' BACKSPACE .`